# Implementing Event Listener / Observer Pattern with GreenDao

Tags: android, observer-pattern, greendao, event-listener

I am using GreenDao to maintain database. I am fetching data from two tables and displaying it in ListView. I want to implement event listener or Observer pattern so that I can refresh the UI whenever there is a change (insert, delete or update) in the database.

How can I achieve it? Does GreenDao provide any such thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an existing event bus implementation such as [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/)

With it it's just a matter of adding some annotations to the class in which you want to observe events.

Comment: Can we use content provider with GreenDao?

Comment: Since you know your tables you can always define your provider anyway. If you only need an observer inside your own application why bother with making a provider